# NetBeans Java Project from command line: Working directory is System32

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

If I run my Java program in NetBeans and follow the information given in the output window to run from a command line:

```
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\erdik\OneDrive\Documents\Computing Science Degree\Course Folder\Year 1\Programming 1\Assignment 2 - Year 2 Edit\assignment2\dist\assignment2.jar"
```

The program starts to run, but when it comes to run the following code to open a .txt file (my "database"):

```
System.out.println("Loading database of stored transactions...");
try 
{ 
    file = new File("TransactionDetails.txt");
    inFile = new Scanner(file);
} 
// if the log couldn't be found in the default program location
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)    
{
    System.out.println(CustomMessages.FileNotFound() + 
            System.getProperty("user.dir"));  // display default directory
    System.out.println(CustomMessages.systemExit());
    System.exit(1);  // the program needs the log to function as intended
}
```

It cannot find the .txt file and prints the default directory as the Windows System32 folder.  How can I specify the location to be the Project folder as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an absolute path to the file instead of a relative path. e.g

```
file = new File("C:\Users\erdik\OneDrive\Documents\Computing Science Degree\Course Folder\Year 1\Programming 1\Assignment 2 - Year 2 Edit\assignment2\dist\TransactionDetails.txt");
inFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Fantastic, worked perfectly - thanks.  Command line now uses the absolute path, not a relative user directory for opening the file, great idea!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on the current working directory to be set to anything.

Either provide the file as a class path resource instead or ask the jvm where the class is located in the file system and locate the file relative to that.

For a read only file I would consider providing it as a resource.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do this at first.  Then I added a source folder to NetBeans that included the .txt file, and it worked.  Will keep this in mind for the future - as I knew how to add .jar files etc but not the concept you were suggesting.